# Writing a group as a product of its generators in MAGMA

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, math-software, magma-cas

Let $G \subseteq S_8$ be generated by the elements $s=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 5 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 7 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$ and $t=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 7 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 8 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$.

Now I would like to see how to write the element
$$u = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 8 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 7 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 5 \end{pmatrix} \in S_8$$
can be written as a product of $s,s^{-1}$ and $t,t^{-1}$ in MAGMA (assuming that $u \in G$).

I wrote the following code

```
G<s,t> := PermutationGroup< 8 | (1, 2)(3, 5)(4, 6)(7, 8) , (1, 3, 7, 4)(2, 5, 8, 6) >;
u := G ! (1, 8)(2, 7)(3, 6)(4, 5);
```

Are there any commands to give me my desired result?

Comment: It is better to direct questions about correct usage of software to their respective forums, e.g. in this case [MAGMA forums](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/).

Comment: This appears to be a question about how to use a particular bit of software, rather than a question about mathematics.  As such, I am closing it.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Looks like the group contact information is now on this page: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/contact/

Comment: @rschwieb There is no forum. Is asking for help using mathematical software not on-topic here anymore? Note that this is actually asking for help doing something mathematical, not asking for troubleshooting or installation assistance.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yeah, I said "group contact information" not forum.  Should be approximately the same.  No, I don't think we should field software questions. The problems involved are not usually mathematical. They're more like "you forgot a semicolon there" or "you're using the function wrong."  Even "this is how you write it in this program" is not actually using mathematics.. it's using software.  Even stackoverflow would be better suited.

Comment: TBH it is a bit of a grey area, but the gist of it is that I would not like to have people use this site to debug, or as a substitute for consulting more relevant resources (like documentation or the implementers) first.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I’ve already given my rationale. Please stop misusing the comments to try to litigate it here.  If you feel that strongly you ought to be sussing out the meta topics on the issue for the past few years so you can possibly make a case in meta. Goodbye.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below will do what you want - in  fact the answer is rather easy! This method will work provided that the group is not too big - say maximum order about $10^7$ or maybe $10^8$. Although not really necessary for solving this problem, it computes a presentation of the group $G$.

```
> G<s,t> := PermutationGroup< 8 |
    (1, 2)(3, 5)(4, 6)(7, 8) , (1, 3, 7, 4)(2, 5, 8, 6) >;
> u := G ! (1, 8)(2, 7)(3, 6)(4, 5);
> F<S,T>, phi := FPGroup(G);
> u @@ phi;
  S * T^2
```